# Meteor Up mup deploy fails - Error response from daemon

Tags: meteor, web-deployment, vps, meteor-up, meteor-1.4

I have a Meteor application that I'm trying to deploy on a `VPS`.  I am using [Meteor Up](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) to do this.

By following the instructions I have set up my mup.js file to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '41.185.27.69',
      username: 'root',
      // pem:
      password: 'secret',
      // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
      opts: {
        port: 22
      }
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'HelderbergLink',
    path: '../../HelderbergLink',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://41.185.27.69',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/HelderbergLink'
    },

    dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60
  },

  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

After this is set up I run the following command in my `.deploy` directory:

```
mup.cmd setup
```

Everything setups successfully here, but then when I need to run the next command:

```
mup.cmd deploy
```

It runs through most of the process but then gives me this error:

[image: Deploy Error Image]

I'm not sure what to do to resolve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.` Make sure that port 80 is not already being used on the server you're deploying to.

Comment: I've checked and it's not being used for anything...

Comment: Just a hunch, try explicitly defining the port in your meteor block. I've done this successfully with 2 apps. [Here's a working mup.json](https://github.com/miahal7/simple-ledger/blob/master/mup.json#L22) file from one of my projects. Although this particular config uses port 80, I have been able to change it with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but taking it out was one of the first things I tried (which is why my display code doesn't show it).  So I've already tried that (and various other ports just to check).

Comment: It's been a while so I'm not sure, but I vaguely remember having an issue with root user. Have you tried using the 'ubuntu' user?

Comment: No I haven't, will need to set that up...